# Shifting bottom half of a diamond

Tags: c, split

I have the code that prints out a diamond with 15 rows split in half horizontally in C, what I'm trying to do is, to translate the bottom half over a couple spaces so that its uneven with the top half. How would I go about doing that?

```
#define TR 15

int main () {

    int row, col, numstars = 1, rate = 1, half;

    for(row = 1; row <= TR; row++)
    {
        half = TR / 2;

        for(col = 0; col < half + 1 - numstars; col++)
        {
            printf(" ");   
        }

        for(col = 1; col <= 2 * numstars - 1; col++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }

        if(numstars == half + 1)
        {
            printf("\n");
            rate = -rate;
        }

        numstars = numstars + rate;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an `offset variable` initialized to zero to `space loop` (first loop), then when you are reversing the rate increase the offset to the number of spaces you want to shift

Something like this: http://codepad.org/i6d99lc7